# ¿Como llenar un listbox a partir de un checklistbox en MS Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Buenas compañeros, resulta que estoy haciendo programa en `MS Visual Basic` en donde tengo un **checklistbox** que se llena a partir de un **combobox**, que según lo que escojo en el **combobox** se genera la lista en el **checklistbox** al dar click en un botón, lo que quiero hacer ahora es que lo que yo seleccione en el **checklistbox** saque los nombres y los ponga en un **listbox** aparte que tengo, es posible hacer esto con un ciclo?, como podría hacerlo?. 
adjunto imagen de mi formulario.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código del botón generar lista:**

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If comboescalafon.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            lista.Items.Add("kevin")
            lista.Items.Add("jeison")


        ElseIf comboescalafon.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            Button2.Enabled = True
            lista.Items.Add("pablo")
            lista.Items.Add("andres")
            lista.Items.Add("douglas")
            lista.Items.Add("chepo")

        ElseIf comboescalafon.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            Button2.Enabled = True
            lista.Items.Add("caralos")
            lista.Items.Add("camila")
            lista.Items.Add("jose")
            lista.Items.Add("estela")
            lista.Items.Add("harold")
            lista.Items.Add("jhon")


        ElseIf comboescalafon.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            Button2.Enabled = True
            lista.Items.Add("felipe")
        ElseIf comboescalafon.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
            Button2.Enabled = True
            lista.Items.Add("juan")
            lista.Items.Add("manuel")
            lista.Items.Add("gers")
        ElseIf comboescalafon.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
            Button2.Enabled = True
            lista.Items.Add("juan")
            lista.Items.Add("daniel")
        ElseIf comboescalafon.SelectedIndex = 6 Then
            Button2.Enabled = True
            lista.Items.Add("alejandro")
        ElseIf comboescalafon.SelectedIndex = 7 Then
            Button2.Enabled = True
            lista.Items.Add("homero")
            lista.Items.Add("maguie")
            lista.Items.Add("lissa")
        ElseIf comboescalafon.SelectedIndex = 8 Then
            Button2.Enabled = True
            lista.Items.Add("bart")

        End If




    End Sub
```

Quisiera agregar la funcionalidad que les comento en el botón añadir que esta en mi formulario.

Comment: Bienvenido SO en español te invito a que de un recorrido [tour] y puedas ver como hacer preguntas que sean aceptadas en la comunudad [ask]

Comment: No logro entender la app y el problema, en tu descripción dices ** checklistbox que se llena a partir de un combobox** y lo que realmente haces es llenar el listbox, o yo lo malinterpreto ?

Comment: hola silvestre, la verdad lo que realmente quiero es llenar el listbox con lo que seleccione del checklistbox, en el codigo esta como realmente lleno el checklistbox usando el combobox, cuando selecciono una opcion del combobox, doy click en generar lista y el checklistbox se llena dependiendo la cantidad de nombres que tengo en el combobox que seleccione, y ahora bien, una ves aparece la informacion generada en la lista del checklistbox, selecciono algunas opciones y le doy a añadir, quiero que el boton añadir me pueda mostrar lo que seleccione del checklistbox

Comment: ¿Entonces tu CheckedListBox se llama lista?

Comment: exacto, se llama lista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente lo que harías es hacer un for para recuperar todos los datos que has seleccionado y luego meterlos en la lista (lista1).

Cambia ese nombre con el que tu tienes para tu ListBox y tendría que funcionar.

Lógicamente tienes que meter este código en el botón que usas para cargar tu lista. (Boton añadir)

Espero te sirva

```
       Dim i As Integer    
        For i = 0 To (lista.Items.Count - 1)
            If lista.GetItemChecked(i) = True Then
                lista1.Items.Add(lista.Items(i).ToString)
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: muchas gracias silvestre si me ha servido, te lo agradezco, la verdad no sabia como funcionan los ciclos en el MS visual basic, muchas gracias amigo

Comment: Por nada, si te resultó útil la respuesta márcalo como "Respuesta útil"